# Where can I find commercial flight information?

Tags: data-request, europe, travel

I want to start a data analysis project to analyze flight delay times in Madrid - Barajas airport and relate those to the time / distances used as thresholds to request a compensation from the airline according to European law. However, I haven't been able to find such dataset. I've been looking in the website of the Spanish flight authority, as well as Amadeus, and some other Google-fu did not help me.

But I need, specifically, is a dataset that contains origin / destination routes, the actual timetable and the scheduled one. Does such an API / historical database exist?

Comment: I don't know about historical information, but I have an app on my phone called [FlightView](http://www.flightview.com/) that initially shows schedule arrival, and then gets updated w/ actual time. Their terms of use say 'for your personal and non-commercial use', so you'd probably have to contact them to see about using it for your purpose.

Comment: QPX, a flight api powered by google, might be a good place to start

Comment: QPX is not a free resource, so I'm afraid I cannot afford it.

Regarding FlightView, I'll take a look, thanks.